# Disable Territory Management

Tags: territory-management

We are currently using territory management in SFDC. We want to disable it(we ourselves cannot do it, assume Salesforce can do it).

**What could be the impact of disabling Territory Management?**

Please let us know what is its impact on the apex classes, triggers and reports. As we are using many reports where territories are part of the reports by default, and if we disable territory management should we rebuild all the reports again or the existing reports will continue to work with territories field being removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news! The things have changed since Spring 14 release:

> As of Spring '14, organizations that use *Territory Management* **can
>   disable** the feature if necessary.
>   ...
>   To disable Territory Management for your organization, contact
>   salesforce.com Customer Support.

The territory management configuration and data will be backup for the case if you will need it again. Read more in the Salesforce's guide to the territory management:

[Territory Management Decision Guide Winter ’16](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/tm_decision_guide.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/cce/tm_decision_guide/tm_decision_guide.pdf

> After Territory Management is enabled in your organization, this
>   feature is permanent and cannot be disabled. For these reasons,
>   enable, implement, and test Territory Management in a sandbox
>   environment before enabling it in production.

Maybe you could try escalating the hell out of it with support but as far as I know - once it's on it stays on.

So... I guess you could "disable" it by deleting all territories (or leaving 1 global one)? No idea if it'll work, don't blame me for any damage :) I'd say that everything should pretty much continue to work. You could download all classes, triggers and reports to Eclipse IDE if you haven't done already and run some searches with Ctrl+H for "Territory", "UserTerritory" and so on. Also check the sharing rules on Account and Opportunity.